# Can not see the header text of DatePicker Column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have three DateTime Picker columns in my DataGridView which I was able to achieve from this..

[How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

When I add only one Column of this type like this..

```
Dim col As New CalendarColumn()
        col.HeaderText = "Date"
        col.Name = "Date"
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
```

It works fine. 
But when I add multiple columns like..

```
 Dim col1 As New CalendarColumn()
    col.HeaderText = "Pledge Expiry Date"
    col.Name = "PledgeExpiryDate"
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1)

    Dim col2 As New CalendarColumn()
    col.HeaderText = "Security Maturity Date"
    col.Name = "SecurityMaturityDate"
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col2)
```

I am able to see the Header text of only the `Security Maturity Date` rest of the two columns do not display their header text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed out Something

While adding second and third column you used same object name to assign Header Text and Name

```
col.HeaderText = "Pledge Expiry Date"
col.Name = "PledgeExpiryDate"

col.HeaderText = "Security Maturity Date"
col.Name = "SecurityMaturityDate"
```

Make Correction as

```
col1.HeaderText = "Pledge Expiry Date"
col1.Name = "PledgeExpiryDate"

col2.HeaderText = "Security Maturity Date"
col2.Name = "SecurityMaturityDate"
```